# Only first page is saved to pdf from html using dompdf with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am trying to create a pdf from html using dompdf with codeigniter. I have two html pages. My problem is that only the first page is saved in the pdf file. The second one is gone.

Here is my code :

```
  $this->load->library('pdf');
  $html = $this->load->view('reports_html/couver1','',true);
  $html .= $this->load->view('reports_html/reportContentImageLeft','',true);                                                      
  $this->pdf->load_html($html);                                                          
  $this->pdf->render();
```

other code

```
$this->data['view'] = $this->load->view('reports_html/reportContentImageLeft','',true);
$html = $this->load->view('reports_html/couver1',$this->data,true);
// $this->pdf->load_html($html);
$this->pdf->load_view('reports_html/couver1',$this->data,true);
$this->pdf->render();
```

i did like you said but only prints on the pdf file the first page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>on.plans - reports - cover page 1</title>
        <link href="<?php echo base_url()."css/reports.css"?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page"> 
            <div id="section" class="cover">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="/path/to/officeLogo.jpg" width="300px" height="150px">
                </div>
                <h1>Meeting date</h1>
                <h3>Project name</h3>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php echo $view; ?>
```

i added the view but its not working

thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you tried to output the value of $html after you used the [Assignment operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) in this line `$html .= $this->load->view()` Does it return both pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$data['view'] = $this->load->view('reports_html/reportContentImageLeft','',true);
$html = $this->load->view('reports_html/couver1',$data,true);
$this->pdf->load_html($html);
$this->pdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
```

And in your `reports_html/couver1` view need do something like this `<?=$view;?>`

This solution is not the best - but it is work.